# WYSIWYG FREE for commercial use

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, wysiwyg

I saw there are several questions about WYSIWYG controls, however my issue is I'm looking for a free control they I can use in my commercial/proprietary project.

All the controls I've found so far are LGPL etc. that prevent me from using it in my comm. projects.

Anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF they're LGPL you can add them to commercial projects, the limitation is that you need to attach (if the software is distributable) the LGPL license next to the editor.

Here is a little explanation with a C/C++ program, but may apply to you. http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/439136.html

Comment: Finally someone that is not a violent downvoter! Thanks that link was exactly what I'm looking for. The licences are for lawyers, not for devs. IMO there should be a translation for all the licences from a deves POV.